# Poor Ubuntu performances on VM VirtualBox

Tags: gnome, virtualbox, performance, mate

I've recently tried to install *Ubuntu 18.04 LTS* on *Oracle VM VirtualBox*, cause I wanted to give this version of Ubuntu a chance. So far, I was using *Ubuntu Mate 16.04* which caused no trouble at all.
The first thing I noticed with **Bionic Beaver** was that the input lag is particularly high: I know the virtualization slows down the operating system, but it was not this much on **Mate** desktop environment. After some testing, I came up with these results on the two platforms:

- ~ 0.15 seconds of input lag with **Mate** desktop when using text editors like VSCode or Atom
- ~ 0.30 seconds of input lag with **Gnome** desktop on the same programs, and even on the default terminal

My question is:

- is it possible that all the difference is related to the desktop environment I use?
- if so, is there any tricky way to sensibly reduce the input lag (maybe without changing environment :P) ?

### Further details

- Dell XPS 13 9370 on Windows host
- Both run with 4 processors, 4GB of RAM, 64MB for graphics and 3D Video Acceleration enabled

...and yes, I've tried out VMWare and the differences still remain.

Comment: I can confirm your discoveries, but it is expectable with all bells and whistles of modern GNOME. It eats whole RAM and CPU :) If you need to do your work - use MATE DE. Or Xfce, or LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommending using virt-manager and kvm-qemu as this seems to always be more responsive and snappier than VirtualBox for the virtual machines that I run on my x86 hardware.  I believe the virtualization is possibly more efficient with this than VirtualBox, but it depends on your hardware and what is being virtualized and/or emulated.